# Sharing Bluetooth connectivity over wifi

Tags: android, bluetooth, linux-kernel, wifi, sharing

My computer does not have any Bluetooth capability, however it has WI-Fi capability. My phone has both.

I was asking myself if there is anyway to "stream" Bluetooth over WI-Fi?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Easiest would be to purchase a bluetooth dongle for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tunneling one type of communication through another is generally possible (within the limits of the Android Bluetooth API), but as it is an obscure need you will probably have to write the bridging server to run on the Android device yourself - this is after all a site for questions about software development.  Additionally, it will work best when the app hosting the server is in the foreground, as Android makes no guarantees about keeping services running in the background.

On the PC side, this bridged Bluetooth capability will probably not trivially present as an ordinary Bluetooth adapter, so you would be limited to using custom applications which known how to talk through your bridge.  The exception would be if you also spend time figuring out how to write a device driver for your host operating system which presents it with traditional Bluetooth APIs, at least to the greatest degree possible.